# Checking for null from another method

Tags: c#, nullable

In C#, when I try to check for nulls outside the current method, somehow the compiler does not understand what is going on at compile time. For instance, consider this method:

```
public static class Guard {
     public static void ThrowIfNull(params object?[] args) {
         foreach(var arg in args) {
             ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(arg);
         }
     }
}
```

When I use this method to actually validate parameters of another method, let's say:

```
public void TestCase(string? name, string? email) {
    Guard.ThrowIfNull(name, email);
    
    string _name = name;
    string _email = email;
}
```

The compiler does not understand this null check, and I still get the nullable warning.

The problem here is a few things:

1. I am not interested in null suppression by using `!` after the null check
2. Moving `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(arg);` inside the method actually makes the code ugly
3. I cannot use the `NotNull` attribute on the params array because C# does not understand that I actually mean NotNull for each index of the array

Now how should this problem be solved?

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but rather than `params object?[] args` I'd probably just create generics with as many arguments as I need, along the lines of `Tuple.Create<T1, T1, ... T8>(...)`, and mark all the arguments with `[NotNull]`.  Doing so also avoids boxing if one of the input args was a nullable value type.

Comment: @dbc: Well a better alternative to that would be to write like 20 overloads! I'd like to know how to define to the compiler that this null check is being done elsewhere

Comment: The compiler doesn't know about the "null check" in your other method because the compiler doesn't care what happens inside another method. Ever. It only looks at what is declared in the signature, and any attributes applied to the called method.

Comment: @Logarr: I'd rather say the compiler is too dumb to find what happens in the other method! Not related to the question, but it is very evident that nullable reference types is a badly designed feature in C#. Although it can be disabled, I believe Microsoft is killing C# with too many features.

Comment: Here's the thing though, the new nullable reference type feature is only just enabling compiler warnings for reference types. The actual behavior of the compiler, and the language, is unchanged. It's meant to maker it easier for people to see when null checking should be done because a lot of devs don't do it.

Comment: @Logarr: With such feature, security scanning and code analysis tools take advantage of that and they produce false positive reports. You have no how hard it is to justify they are really false positive when you are working on government projects! This feature is definitely incomplete as of now. Microsoft should either extend it to work correctly or it has to be dropped. Or maybe C# must not be used for these types of projects.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder Again, this feature isn't changing anything about how the language works. It has made it easier for static analyzers to identify a lack of null checks, which is what is giving you the warnings. Just because you didn't have these warnings before doesn't mean the situation they warn about wasn't possible.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder I believe you didn't get the thing: nullable checking is static checking, thus implicitly NOT able to guarantee a bullet-proof code. If you need reliable code, get rid of null: design your libraries so that the null is (almost) impossible.

Comment: @MarioVernari When Microsoft introduces a new feature, no matter what that is, it should be well designed. This feature from my perspective is half complete!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The final answer to the question is that, there is **no way** to define to the C# compiler that the null check is taking place in the other method. This leads to the conclusion that using nullable reference types actually brings a few problems to the code:

1. Null checks cannot be handled centrally. Without such feature, all methods have to individually check for nulls which makes the code lengthier and uglier.
2. It is absolutely pointless to suppress null warnings using the `!` operator.
3. False positive reports can be generated by security scanning and code analysis tools if null checks are not done in the right place (which as I explained earlier makes the code ugly).

This feature seems to be either badly designed or incomplete at the time I posted this answer.

Comment: That's not correct. Looks at the implementation of `ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: That only works on a single type. That's what makes the code ugly!

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: If you believe it is possible, please write a central null handler that handles an unlimited array of objects and post your answer. I will be more than happy to accept it and upvote for that!

Comment: I just pointed out that your statement "there is no way to define to the C# compiler that the null check is taking place in the other method" is wrong as that's exactly what `ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty` does. As someone has already pointed out using arrays for this is not optimal (it causes allocation on every call) so use overloads.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen My answer is relative to my question.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: If you read the question carefully you see that `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(arg);` is part of it. And I mentioned I cannot use `NotNull` attribute. Then after reading those, how can you get to back to recommending me to read `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull` implementation? That is not what I am asking. An answer should be clear and straightforward and not misleading.

Comment: I am not recommending anything. I'm simply stating that your assertion is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

First off, arrays are harder to check for nullability, hence you should favor another solution.

Secondly, I personally prefer to throw "in place" instead to use a function. That's because is useful to see which parameter is null (i.e. I want the see its name). Something like this:

```
public void TestCase(string? name, string? email)
{
    string _name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    string _email = email ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(email));
}
```

Finally, have a look on how the `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(arg)` is internally written. That will give a hint:

```
    public static void ThrowIfNull(
        [NotNull] object? argument, 
        [CallerArgumentExpression("argument")] string? paramName = null
        )
    {
        if (argument is null)
        {
            Throw(paramName);
        }
    }
```

That is, the `[NotNull]` attribute does the job you need.

That being said, I'd rewrite your code as follows:

```
public static class Guard
{
    public static void ThrowIfNull([NotNull] object? arg)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(arg);
    }

    public static void ThrowIfNull([NotNull] object? arg1, [NotNull] object? arg2)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(arg1);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(arg2);
    }

    public static void ThrowIfNull([NotNull] object? arg1, [NotNull] object? arg2, [NotNull] object? arg3)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(arg1);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(arg2);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(arg3);
    }

    // ...etc...
}
```

The piece under test shows no more warning:

```
    public void TestCase(string? name, string? email)
    {
        Guard.ThrowIfNull(name, email);

        string _name = name;    //no warning
        string _email = email;  //no warning
    }
```

Comment: That's what I am currently doing. Writing overloads is not what I am looking for. I need to know how to define to the compiler that I am checking for nulls elsewhere. This post does not answer my question, but only provides an alternative approach.

Comment: Your code also has a problem, it does not capture the original argument name. You should also include this `[CallerArgumentExpression("argument")] string? paramName = null` to your overloads!

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder that's NOT the code I'd use! I'd use the form as the first snippet, where the exception is thrown directly in the test function. That form is the most suggested and also shows the parameter name. That being said, my answer offers a possible solution with the existent framework. Can't see why downvote it.

Comment: I downvoted that because it is not an answer to my question but rather a workaround. The reason why I posted the question in the first place was to find a neat solution. Your code is a nasty solution.

Comment: `Secondly, I personally prefer to throw "in place" instead to use a function. That's because is useful to see which parameter is null` In which case, why not use [`ArgumentException.ThrowIfNull()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception.throwifnull?view=net-7.0), which *will* include the parameter name automatically, without having to type it in.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I refer to the params-ed function, which cannot carry the original names to whatever wizardry you have. As for me, either by coalescing operator or by your suggestion, is fine. I simply don't understand what the user actually wants, yet considers a piece of code "ugly" or not.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately (as others have pointed out) you cannot achieve this with `params`.

I guess you want to avoid "ugly" code where you have to call  `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull()` for each parameter separately.

In this case you *could* write a separate method for each number of arguments that you want to check. Alas, you can't overload these methods if you are using `[CallerArgumentExpression]` to specify the argument names because the compiler will select the overload with the fewest parameters rather than the one you want.

However, given those restrictions you can write something like this:

```
public static class MyArgumentNullException
{
    public static void ThrowIf1Null([NotNull] object? arg, [CallerArgumentExpression("arg")] string? argName = null)
    {
        if (arg == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argName);
    }

    public static void ThrowIf2Null(
        [NotNull]                          object? arg1,
        [NotNull]                          object? arg2,
        [CallerArgumentExpression("arg1")] string? argName1 = null,
        [CallerArgumentExpression("arg2")] string? argName2 = null)
    {
        if (arg1 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argName1);

        if (arg2 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argName2);
    }

    public static void ThrowIf3Null(
        [NotNull]                          object? arg1,
        [NotNull]                          object? arg2,
        [NotNull]                          object? arg3,
        [CallerArgumentExpression("arg1")] string? argName1 = null,
        [CallerArgumentExpression("arg2")] string? argName2 = null,
        [CallerArgumentExpression("arg3")] string? argName3 = null)
    {
        if (arg1 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argName1);

        if (arg2 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argName2);

        if (arg3 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argName3);
    }

    // And so on for all the paraneters you want.
}
```

Then you can write code like this:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // This throws with message:
        // "Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'u')"
        Test("a", "b", null!);
    }

    public static void Test(string s, string t, string u)
    {
        MyArgumentNullException.ThrowIf3Null(s, t, u);

        Console.WriteLine(s.Length + t.Length + u.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: better than my answer, so I'll upvote you. However, all that makes me nonsense: what if you need some other kind of checking? no blame on your code itself, just thinking about the original request.

Comment: @MarioVernari It's such a shame that [they cancelled the `!!` null param checking feature](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/rejected/param-nullchecking.md) from C# 11. :( That would have made things much simpler.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Let's learn (including myself) to answer the question only. `Unfortunately (as others have pointed out) you cannot achieve this with params` is the answer. The rest of it (in my opinion) is superfluous. If you followed my comment you could see that this is not what I am interested in. You both waste your time writing it and waste someone else's time reading it hoping that they can find something useful.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I have the same problem with ChatGPT. If something can be done then one must provide the solution but if it cannot be done, then answer is `cannot be done`! ChatGPT cannot learn that but we are human beings.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder You were trying to use `Guard.ThrowIfNull(name, email);` and complained that it didn't work. I provided a solution that *would* work. If that's not actually what you wanted then I humbly suggest that you work on your question-asking skills, which would appear to be somewhat lacking.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Your answer is similar to this, "How can I create purple color by mixing yellow and blue", "you cannot do that but you can create some nice green if you mix the two"!! You are writing what you like but that does not answer the question.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder It's nothing like that. It shows you how you could write a working version of your `Guard.ThrowIfNull()`, albeit with one overload per number of parameters. I think you also need to work on your comprehension skills.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: That `albeit` is actually ruining your answer.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder  Where in your question did you state that you don't want to have overloads?

Comment: I had a discussion with Mario Vernari! I described to him why I downvoted his answer.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder  I repeat:  Where in your question did you state that you don't want to have overloads?

Comment: @MatthewWatson If you just said "Cannot be done". I would both accept your answer and upvote for it!

Comment: @MatthewWatson You somehow copied Mario Vernari's answer and gave it back to me!

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder OK, you clearly cannot answer: "Where in your question did you state that you don't want to have overloads?". Have a nice life!

Comment: @MatthewWatson: `I cannot use the NotNull attribute on the params array because C# does not understand that I actually mean NotNull for each index of the array`. What do you understand by reading this?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Do you think that I don't already know about the overload solution when I state that?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I am asking about getting it to work on a params array!